# Delay when using JACK & Guitarix to record bass guitar

Tags: sound, audacity

I've recently started using Ubuntu to convert my PC into basic recording home studio. I was surprised that the Rocksmith USB cable was directly recognized and running smoothly, configuring JACK was a bit hard for a newbie like me but I finally achieved it. I also installed Audacity so I can record the sound and there is were my problem starts. There's a serious delay between the MP3 files I play and the recorded sound of the bass guitar. While playing everything sounds just fine but once recorded there's tming problems between the MP3 file and what I record. Anyone had the same problem? Any solutions so the timing can get as perfect as possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [jack_capture](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/jack_capture.1.html) instead of audacity to record.

```
sudo apt-get install jack_capture
```